# Magnetic core for hall effect sensor

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

[image: core]Welcome all. In my recent design I moved bit away from electronics and into world of physics. I need to gain better understanding of magnetic core design to be precise round core with two airgaps. I am looking for relation between size of airgap and radius of a core and its effect on permeability and magnetic saturation. I have very basic understanding of electromagnetism therefore my question might sound basic and unprecise.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about a doughnut shaped magnet with a air gap on each side.  You have not indicated whether it is a permanent magnet or one driven by current carrying coils.  A Hall effect sensor would be used to measure the field in the gap but has no magnetic field of its own.

Comment: Yes, it is doughnut shaped. It is not permanent magnet. Its purpose is to “focus” magnetic flux. Something similar to arrangement in this picture.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.encyclopedia-magnetica.com%2Fdoku.php%2Fair_gap&psig=AOvVaw2MqSWrP1UYxVLTP0cHQJFe&ust=1582041227501000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPiV6Y352OcCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE

Comment: I've seen a meter which I think was for measuring AC current in a conductor.  It had a laminated iron loop which was hinged so that it could be opened, placed over the conductor and then closed.  A signal processing coil would produce an AC output which depended on the current n the conductor.  If a Hall effect sensor were placed in a gap in the iron loop, that could give an indication of a DC current in the conductor. Since the response of the iron loop may not be linear, any metered output may need to be calibrated over the range of use.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is exactly arrangement I am working with Hall effect sensor being placed in air gap on both sides of half circle. It is very typical arrangement for DC/AC current clamp. However, I want to take my understanding of this design to next level. I am very interested in relation between geometry, material and permeability of material. Since my background is in electronics, I have little knowledge of electromagnetics in terms of physics. Ideally, I would like to learn how to select appropriate core for given hall effect sensor sensitivity and signal frequency.

Comment: I don't see a need for two field sensors.  Your sketch shows only one.  For DC measurements, your core should have little or no remnant magnetic field. (The hysteresis loop should go through the origin.)  With a single current passing through, saturation is not likely to be a problem.

Comment: Having two sensors doubles the precision also feeding inputs of two sensors into instrumentational amplifier takes care of DC bias of Hall Effect Sensor as common mode signal is rejected. 
"....saturation is not likely to be a problem." Yes, agreed for small current yes. My goal is to quantify size of the toroid and type of material to e.g. calculate smallest size applicable for let’s say 100DC and equivalent RMS in AC. I suppose my question is not precise as don’t know much about electromagnetics at the moment.

Comment: I suppose what I am really asking is how one would select toroid core for specific application that is not transformer application?